# On the numerical computation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition

Given a matrix $A$ of order $n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, applying the *shifted QR algorithm*:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& (Q, R) = \text{qrfactor}(A - \omega\,I_n)\,; \\
& A = R\cdot Q + \omega\,I_n\,;
\end{aligned}
$$

with $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ assumed heuristically, after a sufficient number of iterations $A$ is transformed into an *upper triangular matrix* with the respective eigenvalues on the main diagonal. And so far all peaceful. The problem now is to associate an eigenvector to each eigenvalue.

In the particular case where $A$ is a symmetric matrix with real coefficients it's shown that the associated eigenvectors correspond to the column vectors of the matrix $\begin{aligned}\prod_{i=2}^{n_{\text{it}}}\end{aligned} Q_{i-1}\cdot Q_i$, with $Q_1$ corresponding to the *unitary matrix* obtained at the first iteration.

In general, however, the only way I know is to construct the block matrix $[(A-\lambda_i\,I_n)^t\,|\,I]$ for each distinct eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$, reduce it by rows by applying the *Gauss-Jordan elimination method*, obtaining a block matrix of the type $[B \, |\,C]$, where the eigenvectors of $A$ correspond to the rows of $C$ corresponding to the null rows of $B$.

The latter method, however, based on the *Gauss-Jordan method*, isn't numerically stable. Therefore, I was wondering if there was any better strategy for extrapolating *all* eigenvectors, hopefully similar to that for real symmetric matrices.

Thank you!

Comment: The complex QR algorithm reduces $A$ to upper triangular form $T = Q^H A Q$.  You can compute the eigenvectors of $T$ using backsubstitution, i.e., $Ty = \lambda y$. You can transform $y$ into an eigenvector $x$ of $A$ using $x=Qy$. There is no need to use Gauss-Jordan.

Comment: You are very welcome. State-of-the-art software for solving dense eigenvalue problems will first reduce $A$ to Hessenberg form $B = U^H A U$ and then apply the QR algorithm to $B$, further reducing $B$ to upper triangular form $T = Q^H H Q$. The eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ can now be obtained as before. This is an area of active research. The core ideas remain the same, but developing algorithms that are suitable for the ever changing computer architectures will always be a challenge.